# Скрипт контроллера при вызове модели выдает ошибку. Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

Доброго времени суток. 
Начал изучать Laravel 5.4 и столкнулся с проблемой. Вот код ошибки:

[image: Скрин ошибки]

Содержание web.php:

```
Route::get('/', "LocController@index");
Route::get('/params/{id}', "LocController@show");
```

Содержание LocController.php:

```
 namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    use DB;

    use App\Loc;

    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;

    class LocController extends Controller
    {
        /**
         * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\View\View
         */
        public function index(){

            $locacate1 =Loc::all();
            return view('index', compact('locacate1'));
        }
            public function show($id){
            $loc = DB::table('params')->find($id);
            return view('locate.show',compact('loc'));
        }
    }
```

Содержание модели Loc.php:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Loc extends Model
{
    //
}
```

Если же в контроллере прописываю:

```
    public function index(){
    $loc = DB::table('params')->get();
    return view('index',compact('loc'));
```

то все работает, правда без участия модели. 
Где искать? Что смотреть?

В общем, заранее спасибо)

Comment: сама ошибка (2/2) QueryException
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'locations.locs' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `locs`)

in Connection.php (line 647)
at Connection->runQueryCallback('select * from `locs`', array(), object(Closure))
in Connection.php (line 607)
at Connection->run('select * from `locs`', array(), object(Closure))
in Connection.php (line 326)
at Connection->select('select * from `locs`', array(), true)
in Builder.php (line 1705)
at Builder->runSelect()
in Builder.php (line 1690)
at Builder->get(array('*'))  и т.д.

Comment: > Base table or view not found: locations.locs
Таблица locs не найдена

Comment: Видимо миграцию забыли запустить php artisan migrate

Comment: Все это сделано. Фишка в том что с кодом в конце вопроса все работает

Comment: Так я нигде не вызывал таблицу locs, вот в чем и непонятка. Может попробоватб ее создать в бд,?

Comment: @Ushimitsu с какой таблицей должна работать модель `Loc`?

Comment: DB location, table params

Comment: @Ushimitsu см. ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо указать название таблицы, если оно не совпадает с названием модели во множественном числе *(напр., модель `Loc` - таблица `locs`)*:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Loc extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'params';
}
```